# How to get the response value of List<JAXBElement extends Object>?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, soap-client, jaxbelement

I am new in web service and I already get the soap response from web service but in List JAXBElement? it returns object not the value..here's the soap response i am using java

[image]

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "AdditionalStatus", namespace = "urn:ifxforum-org:XSD:1", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected List<JAXBElement<? extends org.ifxforum.xsd._1.AdditionalStatusType>> additionalStatus;



public class AdditionalStatusType {

@XmlElement(name = "StatusCode")
protected Long statusCode;
@XmlElement(name = "ServerStatusCode")
protected String serverStatusCode;
@XmlElement(name = "Severity", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
protected SeverityType severity;
@XmlElement(name = "StatusDesc")
protected String statusDesc;
}
```

Comment: could you atleast show your code ?

Comment: please see the edit thanks

Comment: Now, what is your question ? where are you getting above output ?

Comment: i need to get the string value of

Comment: @XmlElementRef(name = "AdditionalStatus", namespace = "urn:ifxforum-org:XSD:1", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected List<JAXBElement<? extends org.ifxforum.xsd._1.AdditionalStatusType>> additionalStatus;